# Iteration and sequence change

Tags: r

Please see the attached code

```
A <- matrix(c(1,1,1,-1,1,-1,2,3,-1,2,-1,-2),nrow = 4,byrow = TRUE)
b <- matrix(c(0,5,2,4),nrow = 4)
beta <- c(0,5,3)
r <- nrow(A)
iTBD <- 2

s <- seq_len(r)[-i]

for(iWs in s){
  Aq <- A[iWs, ,drop=FALSE]
  print(Aq)
  bq <- b[iWs, ,drop=FALSE]
  m <- nrow(Aq)
  is.ind <- sum(Aq%*%beta) == sum(bq)
  print(iWs)
  print(is.ind)
  if(is.ind) break
}
```

I am implementing an algorithm where

1) I have to choose each row of a matrix A that is not in iTBD and

a) check if a condition is met then break

b) if a condition is not met I need to create all possible different 
      combination of the rows such as c(1,3), c(1,4), c(3,4) and run the for loop 
      again if condition is met then stop at the specific row combination

c) if (a) and (b) didn't work then I have to take the full rows combination
      c(1,3,4) and check the condition 
if (1) doesn't meet the condition then go to step (2)

2) Add iTBD to the rows and

a) take the 2 rows combination not in (1.a) and check the condition is met, if
      not go to step b below

b) take all the 3 rows combination not in (1.c) and check the condition is 
      met, if not go to step c belwo

c) take the full matrix A and check the condition

The issue I have is how can I use the combination in the loop? I mean take each row alone first then take combination of 2 rows and so on until the condition is met?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand your question completely but this information would be certainly of your help.
You can use this function of `library(combinat)` to generate all the combination one by one in loop.
Each column of the matrix represents the unique combination taking i (here i=2) elements from the vector c(1,2,3,4,5) at a time.

Now you may use these producing desired results.

```r
for (i in 1:n){

combinat::combn(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), m = i) # store the combinations in a list and use accordingly.
}

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
#> [2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  I am aware of the combn function. The idea is to start when (i=1) which gives 5 possibilities and checks if the condition is satisfy for any of the possibility if not then check for the 10 above possibilities and so on